# How to set up firewall on Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, debian, firewall

I have set up Apache, MySQL, PHP, SSH (which I use to connect to the VPS), Node.js, MongoDB and ProFTPd. Now, I want to have a firewall on the system, so that no one hacks the system. For instance, MongoDB is open for all on the default port unless I set it to secure mode and provide a password and so on. But it is recommended to have security mode off, and use a firewall to block requests on that port instead.

How would I set up the firewall? (I am not experienced with Linux, and I can only use SSH.)

Comment: As a caution setting up a firewall on a remote system requires foresight. Or to put it the [Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/shorewall_quickstart_guide.htm) way: Do not attempt to install Shorewall on a remote system. You are virtually assured to lock yourself out of that system.

Comment: @Igarzo Ok. So, I should really just set up a password on MongoDB, and make sure it is secure?

Comment: I believe you should secure your applications, because some security problems cannot be „cured” by using a firewall. Also you should set up a firewall, but make sure you have a way to access the system if something turns out to be wrong. These are just multiple layers of protection.

Comment: @Igarzo I don't know what to block. I could block everything except 80, 81, 22, 21 maybe. But is it insecure not to block ports that no programs on the server are listening to?

Comment: Your question is too vague. What does it mean "how to set up"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on setting up firewalls either. Although I do read a lot on the subject, so I might have met some of the pitfalls. My guess would be to start reading the [IPTables tutorial](http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html) and then a higher-lever configuration tool e.g. [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/). Also some comprehensive pages might help e.g. [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `iptables` tutorial should do the trick.

Positive security is best. Block everything and only allow the traffic you specify.

Layers of security is rarely a bad thing. MongoDB is famous for its insecurities, so I suspect secure mode is a good start.

What hosting provider are you using?

Comment: We're using a host in our country, so it is in a foreign language. But it is a VPS server. I've set up MongoDB with --auth and --ip_bind 127.0.0.1. Isn't this enough? I just need a specific command or more to do the job for me. I'm afraid that I lock myself out if I test tutorials...

Comment: Most VPS servers have a rescue mode, does yours?

Answer (score 0):

Like the guy above, I would suggest [iptables](http://boj.github.com/blog/2011/03/04/rackspace-iptables-batten-down-the-hatches/). Also if your up for another layer of security, which is always a good idea, take a look at [snort](http://www.snort.org/). I am assuming that this is a home server type of setup. If I was you I would seperate my network so the webserver is in a DMZ. For instance My network would look something like this.

```
-----------
| internet |
------------______________________
   |        |_______                 |
   |               |                 |
------------- ------------  -------------
| web server| | LAN      |  |  VPN Pool |
------------- ------------  -------------
```

I would recommend doing something like this if what your doing is going to be in use for an extended period of time. I use a hardware Firebox x700 running [pfsense](http://www.pfsense.org/). pfsense is much simpler to configure rules then iptables because of an existing gui. I also wrote a little tutorial on [installing it on a x700](http://simplyaccomplished.com/tutorials/firebox/index.php?view=1), plus people in the forums are very helpful. If you have a spare box sitting around with 3 nic's you could imitate my network. The thing you have to realize when hosting stuff on your own is not just worrying about your web/db server, but your other, sometimes less updated, LAN computers.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer, but I'm using a VPS.